# Linear mixed models: reference about effect sizes debate

Tags: mixed-model, references, random-effects-model, effect-size

I have heard many times over that there is "ample debate" about whether or not effect sizes (and also p-values) for linear mixed models should be computed and how they should be computed. Is there any good reference that discuss this issue ?